# What is this concrete compartment outside my foundation?

Tags: concrete, foundation, removal

I’m planning to run some PVC conduit through foundation wall (LB body above grade and then down to 12-18” below grade) and some PVC water pipe through foundation wall (below grade).

However, there’s a concrete hole/box adjoining the foundation that contained soil and some plants, and so far I’ve seen there’s some stones about 1 ft deep. I’m wondering if it’s an old coal chute. I don’t see any door in the foundation wall, so maybe it was decommissioned a while ago. Note, my house was built in the 1920s.

Do you see any concerns with breaking up the concrete with a hammer drill/chisel and angle grinder in order to remove enough of it for routing my conduit and pipe? And then filling it in with some gravel and dirt? Later I’ll probably want to expand the patio over this area too.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Is it in a place a coal chute would have been likely? What is in the basement at that place? Does it look like the basement wall has had work consistent with walling-in a coal chute?

Comment: The only concern is how it is attached to the wall.  Is it an add on or built as part of wall.  An add on break away.  A part I would like cut near the wall

Comment: I added a photo of the inside of the wall. Seems like it could’ve been a reasonable location for a coal furnace. However, there’s a decommissioned chimney in the middle of the basement (20 feet from this location), and I know this house also had an oil tank at some point, so I’m not sure how everything would’ve been set up in the past.

Comment: A coal chute would have filled a coal bin. The coal furnace or boiler would have been located a few feet away from the coal bin by the chimney. You'd fill a coal scuttle from the coal bin using a coal shovel and hand-carry the coal in the scuttle to the furnace or boiler.